# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method '__initBubble'

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus-one

I'm getting this error in the Chrome console when I click into the +1 Google button on my web application:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method '__initBubble'
```

When I click on Firefox I'm getting this one with Firebug console:

```
GET https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k...oA8JI/rt=j/rs=AItRSTM1CRWVBre780vPJIUtIKP84_w5jA  200 OK  52ms  rs=AIt...84_w5jA (línea 338)
Cannot resize already-closed iframe I1_1386355082729.
```

I've just added the next HTML:

```
<div id="googlemas">
<div class="g-plusone" style="display: clear" data-annotation="none" data-width="200" data-href="https://itransformer.es"></div>
```

and the next Javascript snippet code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

When I click on the button, it turns into this:

[image: Google+ button]

and the +1 is not added.

I've tried removing the styles and all the attributes except the `data-href` one, but always the same error.

Any suggestion of what I am doing wrong?

**Update: Solved**

The error was due to a bad value on `data-href`. I had "https" instead of "http".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to a bad value on `data-href`. I had "https" instead of "http".